# which python3 returns nothing after Ubuntu 20.04 upgrade

Tags: python-3.x, ubuntu-20.04

After I installed the new Ubuntu 20.04 (update form 19.10), Python seems to have major path problems, and also Jupyter notebooks are not working anymore.

1. `which python3` returns nothing (no response)
2. If I try to install a new Python version with `sudo apt install python3.8`  I get the answer
   `python3.8 is already the newest version (3.8.2-1ubuntu1).`
3. Trying `export PYTHONPATH="/my/former/working/python/path"` also changes
   nothing (still no response to `which python`)

Comment: What does `which python` return?

Answer (score 1):

Did you check if you have Python in `/usr/bin/python3`?

If you do

```
sudo apt list | grep python
```

Do you see the Python package?

I think the best bet for you would be to remove python3 and install it again. I know 19.10 had Python 3.7 and 20.04 has Python 3.8 and that might be causing some conflict.

You can remove the Python package by

***WARNING : USE WITH CAUTION THIS COMMAND MAY DELETE A LOT OF PACKAGES FROM YOUR SYSTEM***

```
sudo apt purge python3
```

and reinstall with

```
sudo apt install python3
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. 

Yes, I see all the packages (numpy, pandas, ...) if I do
```sudo apt list | grep python```

It seems if the wrong Python installation is default, but i don't know how to change that besides the things I already tried.

Comment: did you check if you have /usr/bin/python3 ? what is the output of command

`ls /usr/bin/python*`

Your best be would be to either do 

`sudo apt-get install --reinstall python3`
or 

`sudo apt purge python3
sudo apt install python3`

Comment: THAT "sudo apt purge python3" WILL PROBABLY RUINS YOUR OS MORE THAN REPAIR. (AS IT DID MINE) CONSIDER OTHER SOLUTIONS.